# Is "cancel" a keyword or reserved word in Photoshop?

Tags: user-interface, keyword, photoshop-script

Is "cancel" a keyword or reserved word?

My simple dialog box:

[image]

```
var dlg = new Window("dialog"); 
    dlg.text = "Proceed?"; 
    dlg.preferredSize.width = 160; 

// GROUP1
// ======
var group1 = dlg.add("group", undefined, {name: "group1"}); 
    group1.preferredSize.width = 160; 

// add buttons
var button1 = group1.add ("button", undefined);
    button1.text = "OK";
var button2 = group1.add ("button", undefined);
    button2.text = "Cancel";


var myReturn = dlg.show();

if (myReturn == 1)
{
   // code here
}
```

Works fine. All is well. However replace the string "Cancel" with "Can" and the button no longer functions.

[image]

You need to add extra code in order to regain functionality.

```
button2.onClick = function()
{
  // alert("Byas!");
  dlg.close();
  dialogResponse = "cancel";
}
```

So, what's going on, is "cancel" a keyword?

Answer (score 0):

"Cancel" is not a reserved word. If you change it to can, the dialog will return "can" if clicked (and not "cancel"). Maybe you need to update your code somewhere else to reflect it.

It works with your extra code because you're forcing the return of "cancel".

Comment: Apparently, in ScriptUI – OK and Cancel are "self-defined".